# how to connect i2c peripherals to digispark Attiny85

Tags: oled, attiny85

I am new to micro controllers and I have problem with understanding and connecting I2C devices to Attiny85 digiSpark micro controller.

According to [this picture](https://5p.io/content/images/2015/12/Digispark-Pinout.png) SDA and SCL are on the same pin and I am confused how can I connect any i2c device to this controller. Please can somebody help me in order to achieve this?

To be more specific, I have oled display like [this one](http://www.cash-5.com/pics/OLEDMeter.JPG) and I want to connect it to digispark.

If somebody can help me I will appreciate that! Thanks

Comment: `SCK` is a name of the clock signal in SPI protocol. `SCL` is the clock in the I2C. This pin is just multiplexed. I2C is using two signals `SCL/SDA` only (Well, connecting `GND` would be a good idea too).

Comment: sorry miss typed. I just realized that I made mistake with pinouts.
Can you please help me with documentation for connection digispark and oled display? There are no concrete results when I am googling :?

Comment: So on the picture `SCL` and `SDA` are on different pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the linked image shows SCL and SDA on the same pin.

If you look at the data sheet for the [Attiny](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2586-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny25-attiny45-attiny85_datasheet.pdf) on page 60 you can see that  SDA is on the PBO pin (D0 on the linked picture).

[image]

Comment: Kevin, I made a mistake. I have misplaced SCL with SCK. Thanks for this explanation anyway.